# Create new box instead of overwritting

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to add numerous boxes with Javascript. However, instead of adding multiple boxes it just replaces the first one. Ideally I'd like to to work like this:  (1) Click "Next" to generate a color (2) Click save which will create a box below and display selected color (3) Repeat, creating a new box while keeping the prior box(es)

HTML:

```
    <div id="displayColor"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="controls">
        <button id="previousColor">Previous</button>
        <span id="saveColor"><button>Save Color</button></span>
        <button id="nextColor">Next</button>
    </div>

    <p>Saved Colors</p>
    <div class="savedColorBoxes"></div>                 
<script type="text/javascript" src="colorPicker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
    var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("displayColor");
    var nextButton = document.getElementById("nextColor");
    var saveButton = document.getElementById("saveColor");
    var storedColors = []
    var addNewBox = document.getElementsByClassName("savedColorBoxes")

    nextButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        currentColor = randomColor()
        displayColor.style.background = currentColor;
        storedColors.push(randomColor());
        return currentColor
    });

    saveButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
        for(i = 0; i < addNewBox.length; i++){
            // Add Box
            addNewBox[i].classList.add("savedColorsBox")
            // Update Color of the box to chosen
            addNewBox[i].style.background = currentColor
            }   
    });

function randomColor(){
    //pick a "red" from 0 - 255
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //pick a "green" from  0 -255
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //pick a "blue" from  0 -255
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;
    }

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#displayColor {
    height: 420px;
    background-color: rgb(232, 50, 120);
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 83.88px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    height: 79.88px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}

/*button {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1.0em;
}*/

#controls {
    margin-top: 29.44px;
}

#nextColor {
    margin-left: 200px;
}

#previousColor {
    margin-right: 200px;

}

#saveColor {
    text-align: center;
}

.savedColorsBox {
    height: 100px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: yellow;
}

p {
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 102.3px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    color: white;

}

.currentColor {
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any code that adds a button...

Comment: It's in the HTML with the id of nextColor. The code above successfully generates and displays a random color as well as saves and displays it to a box below. The problem is that once I go and try to save another color it replaces the initial one.

Comment: As stated, there doesn't appear to be any **code** that adds a button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `appendChild` method to add new node into certain container of color boxes.

```
saveButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // new node
    var colorBox = document.createElement('div');
    // color
    colorBox.style.background = currentColor;
    // append into box container
    boxContainer.appendChild(colorBox);
});
```

See full example here - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2f5zdn7h/)